# MySQL IN Clause not working for column name 'index'

Tags: mysql

My schema is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `dump` (
  `index` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete1` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete2` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete3` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete4` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete5` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Yet when I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM dump WHERE 'index' IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

Nothing is returned. I am 100% sure that there are entries with an index of those values. It does not matter if I remove the single quotes from 1,2,3 etc but gives a syntax error if removed from index.

Comment: use backtick ` to enclose index

Comment: Wow. Those SQL subtleties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using reserved keywords as identifiers, use some relevant names. If you still want to do the same, enclose it within **backticks (``)**

```
SELECT * FROM dump WHERE `index` IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

Comment: Note the backticks.  You need to enclose any SQL reserved words with backticks whenever you use them as column, table, trigger, or other names.

Comment: @musiclovingindiangirl - Please provide more context about why your sql solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, Index is reserved keyword. You cannot use reserved keywords as column name. Change the index column name to some another name. There are some other keywords like insert, select etc. Hope so it will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use reserved words as column names, you just have to put backticks around them, as he's done.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, certain words like `SELECT, INSERT, DELETE etc`. are reserved words. Since they have a special meaning, MySQL treats it as a syntax error whenever you use them as a table name, column name, or other kind of identifier - unless you surround the identifier with backticks.

There are two options to solve this issue:

**1. Don't use [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html) as identifiers**

**2. Use backticks** (if renaming is not possible)

So, based on **option #2**:

```
SELECT * FROM dump WHERE `index` IN ('1', '2', '3');
```